# How to block port on wamp server?

Tags: javascript, html, console, localhost, wamp

I made a simple html file with this syntax

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>html_using_div</title>
<!-- <link href="border.css"rel="stylesheet"/> -->
<style>
    .c1{
    background-image:url("i/table2.jpg ");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:local;
    font: italic bold 20px/1.2 arial,sans-serif;

    }

    <!-- .c2{
    background-size:1000px 1000px;
    background-image:url("i/DSC05441.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    } -->

</style>
</head>
<body style="background: linear-gradient(-45deg, red , blue , indigo, white );">
<div style=" width=500px ;height:400px; margin:auto ;  " >

    here was my content
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After execution in browser console I got another div and a javascript file name:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:10029/public/linkverifierhelper2.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me in finding the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling the linkverifier2.js file I think you have the SpeedBit Download Accelerator Plus adware/malware.

You could remove it with any antivirus or antimalware tool.