# Why Firebug always displays some HTML code and external js referenced in HTML panel even the HTML page is itself totally empty?

Tags: javascript

Why Firebug always displays some HTML code and external js referenced in HTML panel even the HTML page is itself totally empty? Here's the proof:

[image]

Any idea guys?

Comment: Could be from your browser extensions.

Comment: which add-on/extension? I have the same issue in Chrome too along with FF.

Comment: This addresses the linkverifierhelp2.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177485/how-to-block-port-on-wamp-server. Not sure where the other one is from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many editors add some elements in preview mode as they are editor specific and added only in preview mode. they never impact your page or right anything in your code. So Do not worry.

For example- if you preview your page in "Brackets editor" then it adds some attribute on tags of the HTML page. But they are just pseudo things.

[image]

in attached image data-bracket-id is auto added in preview mode. but makes no changes in our page or code.

Comment: Ok got it mate.